# PHP SoapClient class not found error on IIS 5

Tags: php, iis, soap, iis-5, soap-client

This is enabled in the php.ini file, but phpinfo() is not showing any Soap details.

Checked:

- Editing the correct php.ini - verified with phpinfo()
- Enabled soap in php.ini (uncommented DLL)
- DLL physically exists in php/ext
- Restarted IIS after changes

Server is IIS5 with PHP 5.2.4

What could be causing this?